# Disable JS beforeunload if button with specific id has been clicked

Tags: javascript, button, onbeforeunload

**Problem:**

I have a `beforeunload` warning sign that is activated if the user try to navigate away from the webpage. I wish to disable this behavior if a user press a specific button.

**JS:**

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
    var confirmationMessage = "Not a good idea - want to reconsider?";

    (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE
    return confirmationMessage; //Gecko + Webkit, Safari, Chrome etc.
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="survey.php" class="btn btn-primary" id="initiatesurvey">Next</a>
```

**Desired output:**

To be able to click the next-button without beforeunload gets activated. I have seen a number of solutions on SO but I am looking for a solution that is pure JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the event listener when they push the button. To do this, you need to use a named function rather than an anonymous function, so you can refer to it when calling `removeEventListener`.

```js
function beforeUnload(e) {
  var confirmationMessage = "Not a good idea - want to reconsider?";

  (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE
  return confirmationMessage; //Gecko + Webkit, Safari, Chrome etc.

}

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", beforeUnload);

document.getElementById("initiatesurvey").addEventListener("click", function() {
  window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", beforeUnload);
});
```

Comment: I can't see what `buttonPushed` is referring to?

Comment: Sorry, that was from a previous version of my answer, I forgot to remove it.

Comment: @Barmar Hi, I will get a pop window says "Unable to get property 'addEventListener' of undefined or null reference" in ie11.

Comment: @Barmar the last line starts with `document`.